# How can I change default export settings for Grease Pencil as SVG?

Tags: grease-pencil

[image]

Now 2.93 released, and I used 'file>export>grease pencil as SVG'.

Default scene option is 'selected' but I want to change it to 'visible'.

How can I change the default option setting?

Comment: Looks like it doesn't come from an add-on and is only available in a beta version, so unless you dive into the source code in C/C++, you can't change it I'm afraid

Comment: @Gorgious It's formal version of 2.93 and not add-on.

Comment: Sorry I didn't even know 2.93 was officially out :) But the other point stands, it looks like it is hard-coded and you can't easily change it. If you're a programmer in C you can try your luck in the source code and build your own version. It may not be worth the hassle though

Comment: @Gorgious I just thought that I could change the setting in preferences...

Comment: Oh, Blender 2.93 is out :)